# Inconsistent behavior of Bash

Tags: bash, grep, io-redirection

I have a file named "open". I open up a terminal, read it's first line into a variable `text` and tried to put all the contents of file except for `text` in a new file called "open.temp" using grep's pattern inversion. Here's the code:

```
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % cat open
# PPPP
QQQQ
RRRR
SSSS
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % text=`head -n 1 open`
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % cat open | grep -v $text > open.temp
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % cat open.temp 
QQQQ
RRRR
SSSS
```

But when I put the same commands in a file called "test.sh", give it executable permission and execute it, it pops an error.

```
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % rm open.temp
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % touch test.sh
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % nano test.sh  
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % chmod +x test.sh 
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % ./test.sh 
grep: PPPP: No such file or directory
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % cat test.sh 
text=`head -n 1 open`
cat open | grep -v $text > open.temp
```

Comment: Why not replace the the second part of the operation by e.g. `sed 1d open >open.temp`?

Comment: You are trying to execute `grep -v # PPPP`: search for "#" in the file "PPPP".  Use quotation marks on `"$text"` so that you are grepping for `# PPPP` instead of `#` in `PPPP`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've never used `sed` actually. :P But what's wrong with my method? It seems to work in the terminal, just not in the file.

Comment: Double-quote your variables.

Comment: @user4556274 : Yup! It worked. Thanks for the explanation. It's more important that the real answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda, or just `tail -n +2 open > open.temp`